# How to fetch nested child entities using parent entity key using datastore api

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Here I'm using Datastore API to create, update & retrieve entities.

My use case is, have to get the child and grand child entities of a parent entity.

My entity structure is as follows:

```
 Company
     --> Employee
            --> Address (Multiple Address entities).
```

Here I have `Company` entity key and I need to fetch `Employee` details along with all the `Address` entities configured to the employee.

Example:

```
Company --> Aaa
     Employee --> John 
                  Address --> California
                  Address --> Redwood
     Employee --> Robert
                  Address --> New York
                  Address --> Washington
```

My query will be as follows:

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

Query query = new Query("Employee").setAncestor(companyKey);
datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
```

My required result should be Employee entities of John & Robert along with the respective `Address` entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appengine documentation says:

**public Query setAncestor(Key ancestor)**

"*Sets an ancestor for this query. This restricts the query to only return result entities that are descended from a given entity. In other words, all of the results will have the ancestor as their **parent, or parent's parent**, or etc. If null is specified, unsets any previously-set ancestor. Passing null as a parameter does not query for entities without ancestors (this type of query is not currently supported)*."

So your code should work fine. It will return all the entities with Aaa as the ancestor i.e; both Employee (parent) and Address (parent's parent) entities.

[Documentation Link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Query.html#setAncestor-com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key-)